# Table-per-concrete-class Inheritance mapping and OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance

My application needs to support using registered users from another system.
This mapping is fine, I can load and query from both tables:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class User {
    private String id; // "username"
}

@Entity
@Table("MY_APP_USER")
abstract class MyAppUser extends User {
    // other properties
}

@Entity
@Table("OTHER_APP_USER")
abstract class OtherAppUser extends User {
    // other properties
}
```

The problem is the mapping in other entities, there are two cases, first case:

```
@Entity
@Table("ERROR")
class Error {
    // other properties
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_app_user")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private MyAppUser myAppUser;
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_app_user")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private OtherAppUser otherAppUser;

    public User getUser() {
        return myAppUser != null ? myAppUser : otherAppUser;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        if (user instanceof MyAppUser)
            this.myAppUser = (MyAppUser) user;
        else if (user instanceof OtherAppUser)
            this.otherAppUser = (OtherAppUser) user;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but is this the correct way to do it?

Second case, this one seems tricky to me, even after reading the docs few times:

```
@Entity
@Table("REPORT")
class Report {
    // other properties
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "REPORT_USER",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "????????"))
    private Set<User> setUsers;
}
```

I can't use triggers to ensure data integrity, so I add two columns every where I need the user: my_app_user and other_app_user. So, I need to specify two columns in the "inverseJoinColumns", how do I do this? I map it twice like I did in Erro class and do the workaround in the gette/setter? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a ManyToMany problem also, I left the code from the original post and instead of using @JoinTable I created the entity for the @JoinTable and used that entity in the mappings.